# Reuse Partial View in Another Module MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a partial view in Purchase module, _Attachment.cshtml. So the structure:

```
View
  Purchase
    _Attachment.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
  Sales
    Index.cshtml
```

How to use _Attachment.cshtml in Sales module? I call @Html.Partial("_Attachment") in Sales Index.cshtml, but I've got "The partial view '_Attachment' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a view in another controller, then you will need to move it into the relevant Views/shared folder

So if using areas and you want it to stay in that area

```
/Areas/{areaname}/Views/Shared
```

If you want to use it in multiple areas or you aren't using areas, then place it in the root shared

```
/Views/Shared
```

Comment: Thanks, I take option 2 without areas, but how about if I don't want to place in Shared, lets say in Common, how to configure it?

Comment: You would need to create a new view engine, change the search locations, remove the original razor engine, and add in your own.  this post shows the fundamentals http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Purchase/_Attachment.cshtml");}
```